# JavaScript Change Background Color On Scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-color

I am practicing Javascript and css. I want to change my background color when scrolling down. I don't want to use library for that. I have followed this [code-pen](https://codepen.io/daveredfern/pen/zBGBJV) demo to learn the logic but he used jquery. I have followed [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_scroll_to_top) for scrollTop .My javascript logic works but it does not work like this [demo](https://codepen.io/daveredfern/pen/zBGBJV). I think I have to target each `div` in order to change the background-color but don't know how.

```js
function showScrollColorChange() {
  //let scroll = window.scrollTop() + (window.height() / 3); 

  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 30) {
    document.body.classList.add('color-violet')
  } if (document.body.scrollTop > 40 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 40) {
    document.body.classList.add('color-green')
  } else {
    document.body.classList.add('color-orange')
  }
}

/* document.body.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  showScrollColorChange()
}) */
window.onscroll = function () { showScrollColorChange() };
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: background 300ms linear, color 300ms linear;
}

.container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 50px;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

p{
  width:50%;
  font-size: 20px;
}

img {
  width:500px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
/* colours */
.color-violet {
  background-color: #7A4EAB;
}
.color-indigo {
  background-color: #4332CF;
}
.color-blue {
  background-color: #2F8FED;
}
.color-green {
  background-color: #4DCF42;
}
.color-yellow {
  background-color: #FAEB33;
}
.color-orange {
  background-color: #F19031;
}
.color-red {
  background-color: #F2293A;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil at eaque in aliquam assumenda. Officiis omnis ex
      sunt quaerat magni. Provident at nihil molestias dolores tempora voluptas laborum aspernatur sint.</p>
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599736375341-51b0a848f3c7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil at eaque in aliquam assumenda. Officiis omnis ex
      sunt quaerat magni. Provident at nihil molestias dolores tempora voluptas laborum aspernatur sint.</p>
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599736375341-51b0a848f3c7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil at eaque in aliquam assumenda. Officiis omnis ex
      sunt quaerat magni. Provident at nihil molestias dolores tempora voluptas laborum aspernatur sint.</p>
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599736375341-51b0a848f3c7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil at eaque in aliquam assumenda. Officiis omnis ex
      sunt quaerat magni. Provident at nihil molestias dolores tempora voluptas laborum aspernatur sint.</p>
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599736375341-51b0a848f3c7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil at eaque in aliquam assumenda. Officiis omnis ex
      sunt quaerat magni. Provident at nihil molestias dolores tempora voluptas laborum aspernatur sint.</p>
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599736375341-51b0a848f3c7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60" alt="">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a dynamic way.

Get all containers elements and add the position of their top to an array:

```
containers = document.getElementsByClassName("container");
var containertops = [];
containertops.push(0);  // add for space before 1st container
for (var i = 0; i < containers.length; i++) {
  containertops.push(containers[i].offsetTop);
}
```

Make an array of the colour classes in the order to be used. It is easy to change the colours and order  doing this:

```
// array of colours to use
var colours = [
  "white",
  "color-violet",
  "color-indigo",
  "color-blue",
  "color-green",
  "color-yellow",
  "color-orange",
  "color-red",
];
```

In scroll function, loop through the array of containers top positions. For each `i` in the loop, use this as an index to get a new colour from the colours array so the colour changes for every container. If there are more containers than colours, use the last colour for the rest.

```
// loop through the containers and add a new colour as the containers change
  for (var i = 0; i < containertops.length; i++) {

    // if this container is at the top of the screen get a new colour class
    if (document.body.scrollTop >= containertops[i] || document.documentElement.scrollTop >= containertops[i]) {
      document.body.className = '';  // clear class

      // if we have not enough colours, use the last colour class again
      colourclass= (i>=colours.length?colours.length-1: i);
      document.body.classList.add(colours[colourclass]);
    }
  }
```

This is the code working:

```js
//dynamically add all containers to array
containers = document.getElementsByClassName("container");
var containertops = [];
containertops.push(0);  // add for space before 1st container
for (var i = 0; i < containers.length; i++) {
  containertops.push(containers[i].offsetTop);
}

// array of colours to use
var colours = [
  "white",
  "color-violet",
  "color-indigo",
  "color-blue",
  "color-green",
  "color-yellow",
  "color-orange",
  "color-red",
];

function showScrollColorChange() {
  // loop through the containers and add a new colour as the containers change
  for (var i = 0; i < containertops.length; i++) {
  
     // if this container is at the top of the screen get a new colour class
    if (document.body.scrollTop >= containertops[i] || document.documentElement.scrollTop >= containertops[i]) {
    
      document.body.className = '';  // clear class      
     // if we have not enough colours, use the last colour class again
      colourclass= (i>=colours.length?colours.length-1: i);
      document.body.classList.add(colours[colourclass]);
    }
  }
}


window.onscroll = function() {
  showScrollColorChange()
};
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: background 300ms linear, color 300ms linear;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 50px;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

p {
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 20px;
}

img {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}


/* colours */

.color-violet {
  background-color: #7A4EAB;
}

.color-indigo {
  background-color: #4332CF;
}

.color-blue {
  background-color: #2F8FED;
}

.color-green {
  background-color: #4DCF42;
}

.color-yellow {
  background-color: #FAEB33;
}

.color-orange {
  background-color: #F19031;
}

.color-red {
  background-color: #F2293A;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil at eaque in aliquam assumenda. Officiis omnis ex sunt quaerat magni. Provident at nihil molestias dolores tempora voluptas laborum aspernatur sint.</p>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599736375341-51b0a848f3c7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60" alt="">
</div>
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil at eaque in aliquam assumenda. Officiis omnis ex sunt quaerat magni. Provident at nihil molestias dolores tempora voluptas laborum aspernatur sint.</p>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599736375341-51b0a848f3c7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60" alt="">
</div>
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil at eaque in aliquam assumenda. Officiis omnis ex sunt quaerat magni. Provident at nihil molestias dolores tempora voluptas laborum aspernatur sint.</p>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599736375341-51b0a848f3c7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60" alt="">
</div>
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil at eaque in aliquam assumenda. Officiis omnis ex sunt quaerat magni. Provident at nihil molestias dolores tempora voluptas laborum aspernatur sint.</p>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599736375341-51b0a848f3c7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60" alt="">
</div>
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil at eaque in aliquam assumenda. Officiis omnis ex sunt quaerat magni. Provident at nihil molestias dolores tempora voluptas laborum aspernatur sint.</p>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599736375341-51b0a848f3c7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any other way you can write this code?  I did not understand what you have done but this is the answer I am looking for. I am a beginner level coder .

Comment: @krisna ok, what do you understand? Do you know arrays and loops?

Comment: `var containertops = [];
containertops.push(0);  // add for space before 1st container
for (var i = 0; i < containers.length; i++) {
  containertops.push(containers[i].offsetTop);
}` why you push twice containertops?

Comment: Also I did not understand the showScrollColorChange(). I know arrays and loops

Comment: It pushes many times! Each push in the `for` loop adds the top position of another container, yes? This is all you need normally, but you have white before first container between 0-20px. The Push(0) adds the top of this to the start of the array manually for the white colour. Does that explain?

Comment: @krisna Then in the scroll function, the loop goes through each of the positions of the containers starting at 0. It compares the top of the screen to the containers until it finds the one on the screen. Let’s say container 3 is on screen. When it finds it, the loop index is 3. This is used as key for colour array to get the colour at that place in the array which is blue. This class is added to container.There is code getting `colourclass`, you can ignore it :) that only is needed if you have less coulours than containers. You can use `i` instead :

Comment: Yes sir. sometimes my brain works so slow. when Arrays, condition, loops comes together, I got confused. Need to practice a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 solutions:

1. You only add classes to your body, so with time body will have every class and its color will be set to last class added, so you should also remove each unused class with `classList.remove('className')`;
2. Just change body background with `document.body.style.background = '#FFFFFF'`, and add comments for each color changed to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

`IntersectionObserver` comes here very handy. You just observer every container.

I have put an custom attribute called `_class` to the element. It holds the name of the class that should be added / removed if the elemen enters / leaves the viewport.

The observer runs off the main thread so its more performant.

To see how it works you need to turn on fullscreen. The threshold is set to 0.9 witch means 90% of the div needs to be visible before the class will be added to the body.

```js
let containers = document.querySelectorAll(".container")

let observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
   entries.forEach((entry, i) => {
      let color = entry.target.attributes._class.nodeValue;
      if(entry.isIntersecting) {
        document.body.className = "";
         document.body.classList.add(color);
      }
   })
}, {threshold: 0.9})

containers.forEach(container => {
   observer.observe(container);
})
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: background 300ms linear, color 300ms linear;
}

.container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 50px;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

p{
  width:50%;
  font-size: 20px;
}

img {
  width:500px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
/* colours */
.color-violet {
  background-color: #7A4EAB;
}
.color-indigo {
  background-color: #4332CF;
}
.color-blue {
  background-color: #2F8FED;
}
.color-green {
  background-color: #4DCF42;
}
.color-yellow {
  background-color: #FAEB33;
}
.color-orange {
  background-color: #F19031;
}
.color-red {
  background-color: #F2293A;
}
```

```html
<div _class="color-violet" class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil at eaque in aliquam assumenda. Officiis omnis ex
      sunt quaerat magni. Provident at nihil molestias dolores tempora voluptas laborum aspernatur sint.</p>
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599736375341-51b0a848f3c7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60" alt="">
  </div>
  <div _class="color-indigo" class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil at eaque in aliquam assumenda. Officiis omnis ex
      sunt quaerat magni. Provident at nihil molestias dolores tempora voluptas laborum aspernatur sint.</p>
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599736375341-51b0a848f3c7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60" alt="">
  </div>
  <div _class="color-blue" class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil at eaque in aliquam assumenda. Officiis omnis ex
      sunt quaerat magni. Provident at nihil molestias dolores tempora voluptas laborum aspernatur sint.</p>
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599736375341-51b0a848f3c7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60" alt="">
  </div>
  <div _class="color-green" class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil at eaque in aliquam assumenda. Officiis omnis ex
      sunt quaerat magni. Provident at nihil molestias dolores tempora voluptas laborum aspernatur sint.</p>
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599736375341-51b0a848f3c7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60" alt="">
  </div>
  <div _class="color-yellow" class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil at eaque in aliquam assumenda. Officiis omnis ex
      sunt quaerat magni. Provident at nihil molestias dolores tempora voluptas laborum aspernatur sint.</p>
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599736375341-51b0a848f3c7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60" alt="">
  </div>
```